# Stopwatch shows only seconds

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I have a program with a `Timer` using the `StopWatch` class.
There is a `Label` that shows Hours, Minutes and seconds like this:

```
label.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", stopwatch.Elapsed.Hours, stopwatch.Elapsed.Minutes, stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds);
```

- I would like to know if it is possible to show only seconds?
- Is it possible to when the clock reaches 60 seconds, it continues? like 61 seconds, 62 seconds, etc.

Comment: What have you tried to accomplish this?

Comment: A Timespan, the elapsed property is a timestamp, has Properties representing totals. IN your case you might want to look at TotalSeconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the elapsed seconds into the label:

```
label.Text = $"{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000}";
```

Or this:

```
label.Text = $"{(int)stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}";
```

Comment: With the caveat that the former will only be discrete seconds, while the second will include a fractional component.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use the `TotalSeconds` property:

```
double totalSeconds = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
```

To assign this value to your `Label`s `Text` property, do the following:

```
label.Text = totalSeconds.ToString();
```

Consider a `cast` to `int` or round the value, if you want to display full seconds only.

Answer (score 1):

[`Stopwatch.Elapsed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed?view=netcore-3.1) is property of struct [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netcore-3.1), which has bunch of properties with names starting with `Total`, for example:

```
TimeSpan.FromMinutes(121).TotalHours  // 2.0166666666666666
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(67).TotalSeconds // 67
```